# How do you close a AsynchronousSocketChannel cleanly?

Tags: java, nio, nio2

My server uses a `AsynchronousServerSocketChannel` that listens for client connections using a `CompletionHandler`.  When a client connection is accepted, the `AsynchronousSocketChannel` is read, again using a `CompletionHandler` to receive the data with no timeout.

So far so good, my client connects, writes data that is read by the server, which is able to respond sending data back to the client via the same socket.

When my client terminates, it calls `AsynchronousSocketChannel.close()`, to close the socket.  When this call is made the server is waiting to read data from the socket.

I had expected the call to `AsynchronousSocketChannel.close()` on the client to translate into a callback to `CompletionHandler.completed` with a read length of `-1` on the server, indicating the socket had been closed, however the callback is to `CompletionHandler.failed` with the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: The specified network name is no longer available.
  at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.translateErrorToIOException(Iocp.java:309)
  at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.access$700(Iocp.java:46)
  at sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Iocp.java:399)
  at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

How should a client close a socket, so that it is not seen as an error on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation on close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousChannel.html#close%28%29) says that it causes 
AsynchronousCloseException or  ClosedChannelException on the other side.

To cause `completed(-1)` the client should call [shutdownInput](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html#shutdownInput%28%29).

However, I would treat AsynchronousCloseException and ClosedChannelException as normal shutdown, along with completed(-1).

Comment: It doesn't say anything about 'the other side'. Both those exceptions should be treated as programming errors, not 'normal shutdown'.

Comment: I've added in the call to `AsynchronousSocketChannel.shutdownInput` on the client-side, which does indeed cause a callback to `CompletionHandler.completed` with a read length of -1 on the server.

Comment: It's a shame the client-side gets a `AsynchronousCloseException` though at least it's not the very general `IOException` and because the client initiated the close, I can add a `closing` flag in order to ignore this error.

Comment: @EJP - do you know of a way to avoid the `AsynchronousCloseException` altogether?

Comment: I was stumped by this behavior as well... Why would you throw an exception if a client *closes* the connection using a valid method? I want to know. That's like your car alarm triggering every time you close the car door...

Comment: The thing is, the exception is translated to java.io.IOException... Which is kind of ambiguous. This has "not well thought out" stink all over it... How the hell am I supposed to know how bad this io Exception is? Do i need to wrap it in extra logic because it was sent to failed method in the handler? Makes me feel dirty just thinking about it and not in a good way.

Comment: In my code, I have actually identified several different ways we're told about closed channels. 1) Trying to initiate operation on a closed channel immediately completes with `ClosedChannelException`. 2) The specialized subclass `AsynchronousCloseException` is when a pending operation aborts. 3) Trying to initiate when the associated group is closed will get you a `ShutdownChannelGroupException`. 4) Any IOException which has _a cause_ set to a `ShutdownChannelGroupException` is a rare breed but means the operation initialization was accepted but failed afterwards because the group shutdown.

Comment: What's the alternative? I don't see one. How can a close "normally" complete a channel operation? The task of driving a car either gets you there or an exception happened. We could have more result sentinel values than just "-1" but this is a bit smelly and I think will lead down the rabbit hole. It's probably not very coherent with many other APIs in the runtime either. Also, using exceptions we have only one unified way of dealing with failures, and we can even learn about new future scenarios/reasons in the future why a channel was closed without being limited to sentinel values alone.

Comment: Anyways, in my case the "other side" was a Java client which only sometimes threw a "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" on read(). I figured as much the server was terminating the connection badly before the client was done. Anyways, solved the problem by changing the server's close procedure from doing only `close()` to `shutdownInput()` + `shutdownOutput()` + `close()`. Thank you for sharing guys! =)

Comment: Adding `shutdownInput()` and `shutdownOutput()` won't have fixed it. It doesn't change anything if the close follows immediately. You must have done something else as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at stack traces and the implementation sources, you might notice that the exception is thrown by the internal `sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl#finish()` method which checks for pending read/write operations. So the only way to avoid this exception is to prevent new asynchronous `read()` and `write()` calls at some point, and that should be a part of the application's logic.

I've dealt with this exception quite a lot, and in most cases the root problem was in the completion handler's unconditional "continue listening" calls:

```
conn.read(src, attachment, new CompletionHandler<Integer, T>() {
    @Override
    public void completed(Integer result, T attachment) {
        // Some business logic here
        
        // Below is the problem - unconditional read() call
        conn.read(src, attachment, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void failed(Throwable t, T attachment) {
        // Exception handling
    }
});
```

To gracefully close the connection, there should be no unconditional async read/write calls. To achieve that, one might need to send an additional message which would mean that no new async data is expected and it's safe to close the connection. And the correct pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
conn.read(src, attachment, new CompletionHandler<Integer, T>() {
    @Override
    public void completed(Integer result, T attachment) {
        // Some business logic here

        if(continueListening()) {
            conn.read(src, attachment, this);
        }
    }
    
    // ... 

});
```

Comment: No need to call `close()`?

Comment: @JinKwon the idea is to break the handler's recursive reads before closing the connection, thus avoiding the `AsynchronousCloseException`. That's of course if your app's logic allows for it. If not, one can close the connection and handle the exception in the `failed` block